How to fix the hard drive problems
My laptop suddenly turned off, after that there was a problem with the hard drive.
Now I started Ubuntu from a flash drive. What could be the problem? Is it time to change the hard drive?
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Warning! Read error 0! Misbehavior now likely!
Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Error 5 reading partition table for CRC check!
Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: OK
Main partition table: ERROR
Backup partition table: ERROR

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 938B1BF5-F56F-42C6-AA2C-CBAFEBEF2C9F
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2029 sectors (1014.5 KiB)

and
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3EAC5B3E-249C-4632-8D96-33E05D790BF4


You may find this Ubuntu Document of help. .. Bad disks are bad news and often the best option is just to swap them out.

This question is similar to: Retrieve data from disk after dd. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
